# Calendar table with changing start date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I work in an educational department where the start date of our academic calendar changes every year. Some years it might be week 9 of the year, some years it might be week 10. There is no formula used to figure out this start date, it's based a combination of factors and is picked by humans.

I want to be able to compare calls received in week 1 of the academic calendar 2017 to calls received in week 1 of the academic calendar 2018 and 2019.

I am using PowerBI desktop and trying to create a calendar table that includes a column "academic calendar week" or similar.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to offset start date of the calendar by a different number of weeks for each year?

Comment: I would recommend to add Academic years and their attributes (week number, semester, etc) to the regular Calendar table, and and manage them at the data source (database or whatever you are using). This is the simplest and most robust solution; don't try to use DAX for this task - it's too complicated.